# What's general design for a class with both ORM to database and many non-database methods?

Tags: oop, orm, class-design

I'm new to class design with ORM and trying to design a class that originally is just a ORM class mapped to database, but now needs to be extended with many operations/methods.

## Scenario

Suppose I have already got a ORM class "Phone" with some fields like "messages", "phone_records", "photos", etc. It was just used to insert/query these info to/from database. But now, I need to add some non-database operations for it, like Phone.call(), Phone.set_alarm(), Phone.take_picture(), etc.

## Question

I can think of two options: 1) extend the existing class "Phone" with new methods, or 2) define a new class "PhoneOper" for the new methods and keep the class "Phone" only contain fields in database and only for database operations.

The #1 looks wired to me that an ORM class with so many other operations. But for #2, I don't know how to map them together the best way. (like "PhoneOper" can easily find "Phone" to insert itself into database, or a query result "Phone" can easily find corresponding "PhoneOper" for operations.

Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: I think uncle bob's latest blog [Classes vs. Data Structures](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2019/06/16/ObjectsAndDataStructures.html) just makes my understanding clear. ORM are objects not data structures. In my case, I should choose #1 without being restricted by the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

The questionable part here is having a `Phone` class that is responsible for data storage, besides already being a `Phone`. The `Phone` class should be concerned about being a `Phone` only. A `Phone` object has data and methods. You can extend the methods as you say, and you probably need to persist the `Phone`(s) state (data). You just need to ask the `Phone` for the data to be able to deliver this data to some other entity responsible for serialization, to store it the way you like. By using an already made ORM, or some database interface class you write yourself.

To use the database facilities it is true that you can use an API of an external db or ORM object or class. You can also keep some reference to this external entity inside the `Phone`, to be able to refer to its methods from inside the `Phone`. Or sometimes you inherit from the ORM class, to have its methods available.

Unless this last case is a requirement to use the ORM (it looks like it is), it makes the `Phone` look like an ORM, which it isn't, and I would prefer to just use a DB API, or a database service layer from the `Phone`.

To extend the `Phone` by subclassing with different or additional features looks ok to me. You can also ponder the definition of additional interfaces with features and make some phone classes use/implement them.